# Identifying type juggling issues before PHP upgrade to PHP8

Tags: php, php-8

Currently, I am sitting on PHP5.6 and would be updating to PHP8 soon. I used PHPCS to check the compatibility issues and was able to fix them before upgrading to PHP8.

However, I found some issues related to type juggling in the code during testing such as:

```
$x = "";
$x['test'] = "xyz";
print_r($x); //Warning: Only the first byte will be assigned to the string offset in /tmp/8dw2cmkrbq0pcq/tester.php on line 4 Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in /tmp/8dw2cmkrbq0pcq/tester.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /tmp/8dw2cmkrbq0pcq/tester.php on line 4
```

This piece of code worked well in PHP5.6.

Unfortunately, the issue was not detected by PHPCS and now I am wondering if there are more issues like this in the product.

Now, I want to know if there is a way to detect such issues before I upgrade to PHP8? It would be really helpful if I could get a hint on how to find such issues before I upgrade to PHP8.

Comment: Type juggling issues can't generally be detected with static analysis, it depends on the dynamic control flow.

Comment: However, PhpStorm has some clever data flow analysis, it might be able to detect problems like this.

Comment: Yeah, I actually thought that. Maybe because these issues can be detected only during execution, thats why it is difficult to track them.

Comment: Tried using PhpStorm, unfortunately it did not detect any of the issues like above. I revert my change and then tried to find that using the IDE but no luck.

Comment: Just as an idea: as there are so many changes between PHP 5.6 and PHP 8, maybe it would be easier to upgrade step by step? To PHP 7 first, check that everything works by running your application with that for some weeks, and then to PHP 8?

Comment: It would mean testing the whole system twice plus it still doesn't help figuring out the problems. And it is hard to do so on a large project in production environment twice. So I wouldn't do it.

Comment: Well, as your whole application should be put under automated tests anyways, that should not be too difficult....

Comment: Yeah, we have approx 80% test coverage, thats why I am here, to check the remaining.

Comment: Weirdly, this particular case actually changed behaviour in PHP 7.1, and then became an error in 8.0: https://3v4l.org/CZBLf Similar code with an integer offset changed behaviour _silently_ in 7.1, and issues a Warning in 8.0: https://3v4l.org/hU6Ig

Comment: A high test coverage like that is impressive! To go further on my comments: they might not cover each and every corner case, and going step by step could help to avoid that any features **deprecated** in PHP 7 and **removed** in PHP 8 might break cases that are not covered in the tests. That's where running on PHP 7 first for some time might help to not run into undetected cases which might be difficult to be resolved in production

Comment: Also, to come back to the initial question: wouldn't that high test coverage yield exactly that error, if you run the code using PHP 8? Which tools are you using, only phpcs or also stuff like PHPStan? Maybe phpcs does not contain rules to cover your use case?

Comment: @NicoHaase From the checks I did above, running on 7.0 wouldn't detect this at all, and running on 7.1, 7.2, or 7.3 would have behaviour that matched neither 5.6 nor 8.0; so _in this particular case_, I don't think a two-stage update actually helps. In other cases, though, it certainly would, since a lot of Warnings and Deprecation notices would be issued in 7.x for things that would then become Errors in 8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to detect this type of issues using https://github.com/phan/phan. Here is the sample issue that was caught.

```
{
"type": "issue",
"type_id": 10030,
"check_name": "PhanTypeMismatchDimAssignment",
"description": "TypeError PhanTypeMismatchDimAssignment When appending to a value of type '', found an array access index of type 'hobbies', but expected the index to be of type int",
"severity": 5,
"location": {
    "path": "PQR/models/XYZModel.php",
    "lines": {
        "begin": 171,
        "end": 171
    }
}}
```

Thank you for your support guys.

Comment: Please suggest and I would love to add more details to the answer.

Comment: I would say the answer is to use a static analyzer, also known as linter. I've worked with PHPStan and Psalm in the past, both have an enormous benefit.

Comment: I used PHPCS too, but it did not detect these issues.